# Comparing logistic regression models b/w non-independent samples

Tags: regression, logistic, sampling

I have run a fully adjusted logistic regression model for a sample whose data was collected in the year 2000. The outcome is retirement, and the predictors are individual characteristics, like age, gender, etc, and some health predictors as well.

I have run a second logistic regression model for a sample whose data was collected in the year 2008, with the same outcome and set of predictors.

I now want to compare the model coefficients using various methods, i.e. as an interaction term (predictors x year (2000 or 2008)), and using a Wald test to compare logit coefficients between the two "groups".

My problem is that about 50% of the people sampled in 2000 were sampled again in 2008 (that is if they didn't have the outcome in 2000, i.e. had not yet retired).

So I am wondering what are the limitations this setup causes? What should I be checking (in addition to the degree of overlap) that can estimate the effects of this design? So for example, how can I quantify the "issue" to explain to my readers the degree to which it is a problem? And finally, is there anything I can do to reduce any weaknesses the design causes?

Comment: Do you have the times at which subjects retired, or times at which follow-up ended for non-retired subjects? If so, you could fit both data sets into a single survival model and check for time effects within that model.

Comment: No unfortunately I only have Yes/No response to retirement question for the two different years.

Comment: Is part of your goal to compare the the two years?

Comment: My goal is to be able to say whether or not the significant predictors of retirement changed between 2000 and 2008, and quantify it somehow, so not just descriptively.